# Init not being called when using ShowViewModel<T> in MVVMCross MvX

Tags: windows-phone-8, viewmodel, mvvmcross

i'm seeing some weirdness in my Windows Phone app with MVVMCross.

I use `ShowViewModel<MyViewModel>();` to load a new view on a command being executed.

I've changed that to:

```
ShowViewModel<MyViewModel>(new { First = "Hello", Second = "World", Answer = 42 });
```

But Init isn't being called in the MyViewModel, MyViewModel inherits from another class that in turn inherits from a MvxViewModel, I've even changed both view models to inherit directly from MvxViewModel.

If i used:

```
Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>().LoadViewModel(MvxViewModelRequest<MyViewModel>.GetDefaultRequest(), null);
```

Init get's called, same for the InitFromBundle, I passed a bundle containing that test object but I didn't get the values passed through.

Init method just looks like this:

```
public void Init(string First, string Second, int Answer)
```

I'm totally confused, setup, app.cs all look like the navigation example, any ideas what I might have forgot?

Windows 8.1, VS 2013, Hot Tuna, Windows phone 8.

---

Init methods:

```
public void Init()
{
}

public void Init(string First, string Second, int Answer)
{
    // use the values
    var meh = "";
    Mvx.Trace("Init called in {0}", GetType().Name);
}

protected override void InitFromBundle(IMvxBundle bundle)
{

}
```

Comment: Is there any trace telling you what might be failing?

Comment: none, just says the view model loaded, anything I can do to make it more verbose?

Comment: Literally just seeing mvx:Diagnostc: 7.54 Showing ViewModel MyVewModel, no errors, executes ShowViewModel with the object fine, it just never seems to call Init either with an empty constructor, with a a constructor that matches the object passed in ShowViewModel or InitFromBundle.

Comment: I assumed you were seeing https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Platform/MvxSimplePropertyDictionaryExtensionMethods.cs#L159 - but if you aren't setting that exception or any trace then I don't know.

Comment: No, I didn't see that at all.

Comment: So everything looks good after walking through that source code with debug symbols, bundle gets created as expected.

Comment: what platform? It seems that ShowViewModel is bugged in WP8.1 (WinRT api)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ShowViewModel<NameOfViewModelClass>(new { First = "Hello", Second = "World", Answer = 42 });` instead

Comment: Sorry my mistake, that is what I'm using, typo in question.

Comment: it executes just fine, but none of the Init methods are getting called on the MyViewModel.

Comment: is init method located in your ViewModel class?

Comment: Yes, grabbing MvX from Git and using the debug bin's to figure out whats going on now.

Comment: Sorry, grabbed the debug symbols, struggling to get them to load, i'm sure i'll get it working in a sec.

Comment: Arg! I'm still stumped, walked through DictionaryExtentionMethods, watched it build a bundle, no problems, any pointers on where I should look next? IoC?

Comment: Try to leave just one Init method, for example that one with parameters, but at all it should work without any extra manipulation, so I suggest to recreate the project (I know that it's a solution at all, but it may help)

Comment: So,

In my View's code behind I'd strongly typed the ViewModel, std, public ViewMode with a private MyViewModel, I'd set that private to a new instance of the ViewModel, that killed everything.

user error! I can't mark this as an answer for 8 hours apparently, but this is fixed now, thanks Choper and Stuart